my images won't float horizontally & center instead of vertically & center
so my images i want to float are still left-aligned to my page when i use the align: center
but when i use display: flex, they all center, but vertically. im trying to get them to be horizontal but i don't know what's affecting them. im trying to center them over the second (pink) box


#base {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1300px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#left {
  width: 260px;
}

#right {
  width: 300px;
}

#center {
  width: 850px;
  background-image: url(https://fancyparts.com/fancyparts/cg/pattern/strip_a/strip_a50.gif);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 5px outset #ff8282;
}

#headliner {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#navi {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: url("") 30 fill round;
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.centerimage {
  width: 50%;
  size: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/YSp3TDc2/v.gif" style=";" margin-bottom:="" 18px;="" class="centerimage">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jjZXT6KH/i.gif" style="vertical-align: center;" margin-bottom:="" 18px;="" class="centerimage">
<div id="base">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="headliner"></div>
    <div id="navi">
      <div id="titulo">navigate</div>
      <button class="buttonA"><a href="(LINK)"> homepage </a> <img src="" width="15"> </button>
      <div id="titulo">socials</div>
      <button class="buttonA"><a href="(lINK)"> about me </a> <img src="" width="15"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div id="top">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
</div>




Are you just looking for align-items: center;?

@async-await adding that doesn't change my code at all

I'm not sure what your desired output is supposed to look like, and the html provided is not giving me a clear idea of how you expect the content to be laid out. It looks horizontal right now. If you wanted a column instead of a row, you could use flex-direction: column; on the flex parent.

i stated that when i use display: flex, which i expected to center my images, it turned all my images into a vertical position-- which is not what i want. i want the images to be centered and horizontal. but as you can see, its not centered. adding flex-direction:column doesn't change anything to my html either. like i said, i just want the images to be centered, or at least centered over the second box.

So you're saying the aspect ratio of your images is changing? Or they're not enforcing their width?

I tried to clean up your html and make it more clear what you're trying to do- maybe turn your code into a snippet, but the html is invalid. I think it would be better if you attached a MS Paint mockup of what you're trying to accomplish.

i guess? i just want the images centered. in the page. but when i try to do that, all the images in the container go down vertically in the center. i want them to be horizontal, not going down, just on the page. but my code, after tweaking it 20 times, wont let me do that. does that make sense? i just need help with the variables that will let me make the images horizontal and center. not vertical.

https://i.ibb.co/LvXqyVw/Screenshot-2024-05-04-at-4-38-35-PM.png

I made you a snippet. You had a </div> too many and were also missing a }  at the end of the stylesheet

i don't understand the point of your snippet. unless i cant properly run it, it didn't change any of the problems i described.

https://ibb.co/pQgBqMw Here's an image for reference, but what it's attempting to explain is: You could make a container with the long element and your images in their own wrapper, and make it a flex column, aligned to the center. However, the images would be at the top of the element. The advantage to this is, the page would respect the height of the content, and you wouldn't have to figure out margins or worry about the content being clipped. unlike using the absolute alternative, where you make the images a child of the long element and make the long el relative position. I'll add a demo

Here's a demo of how to accomplish your design referenced in your image, with consideration to your current html. I think some things in your html could use a bit of clarity, but I'm trying to stay true to the structure of your project.
I created a wrapper for the long element, and a wrapper for the images. I placed the images as a child of the long element. By default, the long element is a flex column which aligns its items to the center. This helps the page respect the height of the image content, however it's not quite true to your image.
Staying more true to your image, when the checkbox is checked, I positioned the images absolutely while the parent is relatively positioned to anchor my bottom and left selector. finally, I use translate to center it, because the left property will position based on the top left corner.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.


#base {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1300px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#left {
  width: 260px;
}

#right {
  width: 300px;
}

#center {
  width: 850px;
  background-image: url(https://fancyparts.com/fancyparts/cg/pattern/strip_a/strip_a50.gif);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 5px outset #ff8282;
}

#headliner {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#navi {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: url("") 30 fill round;
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.centerimage {
  width: 50%;
  size: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.long-el-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  user-select: none;
}

#absolute-toggle:checked ~ #base .long-el-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

#absolute-toggle:checked ~ #base .long-el-wrap .img-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% 0;
}
<label for="absolute-toggle">
  Toggle Absolute Style
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="absolute-toggle" />

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="base">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="headliner"></div>
    <div id="navi">
      <div id="titulo">navigate</div>
      <button class="buttonA"><a href="(LINK)"> homepage </a> <img src="" width="15"> </button>
      <div id="titulo">socials</div>
      <button class="buttonA"><a href="(lINK)"> about me </a> <img src="" width="15"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="long-el-wrap">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/YSp3TDc2/v.gif" style=";" margin-bottom:="" 18px;="" class="centerimage">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jjZXT6KH/i.gif" style="vertical-align: center;" margin-bottom:="" 18px;="" class="centerimage">
    </div>
    <div id="center">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div id="top">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
</div>




An image is, by default, an inline element. Think of it like a word in a sentence. You can’t center an individual word, but you can center a paragraph containing a single word.
The simplest solution is to put your images inside a div or p wrapper, then style the wrapper with text-align: center.

To align images horizontally but keep them left-aligned, learn CSS Flexbox. Use properties like justify-content and align-items on your container (#base). Check for conflicting styles on your images. Understanding Flexbox will help you fix similar layout problems easily.
(edit): Also you should use css externally. Search up how to use css externally.
